# json obj into javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have this json file

```
[
{"name": "name1", "start": "01/03/2017", "end": "01/03/2017"},
{"name": "name2", "start": "01/03/2017", "end": "01/03/2017"},
{"name": "name3", "start": "01/03/2017", "end": "01/03/2017"}
]
```

and -i need this result in javascript

```
var cubes = [
    {name: "name1", start: "01/03/2017", end: "01/25/2017"},
    {name: "name2", start: "01/04/2017", end: "01/26/2017"},
    {name: "name1", start: "06/15/2017", end: "06/18/2017"},    
    {name: "name3", start: "01/05/2017", end: "01/27/2017"}
];
```

I have:

```
cubes = [];

$.getJSON('urlaub.json', function(data) {

    var obj = data;
    for (elem in obj) {
        console.log(obj[elem]);
       cubes.push(obj[elem]);
    };
});
```

But Array cubes is ever empty and .json firefox means syntax error in json File Line 1. But Objects were created. Array is ever empty.Tryed so many. What is wrong?

Comment: `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: i tryed json parse too

Comment: where is `{name: "name1", start: "06/15/2017", end: "06/18/2017"},` coming from?

Comment: thats my first array i created. but i need this from an external file. so i was trying it with a json file. this means the rsult i need

Comment: So is the getJSON call actually getting into the success method? Are you forgetting that getJSON is synchronous? `var cubes; $.getJSON('foobar.json', function(data) { cubes = data; callMethodThatUsesCubes(); });`

Answer (score 0):

JSON.parse is as @kukkuz said is what you are after

```
var data = JSON.parse(`[
    {"name": "name1", "start": "01/03/2017", "end": "01/03/2017"},
    {"name": "name2", "start": "01/03/2017", "end": "01/03/2017"},
    {"name": "name3", "start": "01/03/2017", "end": "01/03/2017"}
]`)

console.log(data); //shows an array
```

For clarity, the backtick ` is there to allow this to be on multiple lines. You could simply reduce this to a single line and add normal single quotes.

To use your example -

```
var cubes = null;

function getMyData() { 
    return $.getJSON('urlaub.json', function(data) {
       return data;
    }).error(function(err) { alert("error - " + err) });
};

getMyData().then(function(data){
    cubes = JSON.parse(data);
});
```

Comment: thats what i tryed. dont works $.getJSON('urlaub.json', function(data) {

 set = JSON.parse(data);
 cobes = set;
});

Comment: and the result from json is this what i need in javascript (as sample)

Comment: Can you tell us the error in the console... as I tested this in mine and it works.

Comment: TypeError: cubes is null - <anonym>

Comment: please see error handling, sounds like your json call is not working

Comment: i get the json arrays...THAT isn´t the problem. but outside the json function is cubes an empty array

Comment: ok, you are trying to consume the variable before it has been filled, see the 'then' pattern above

Comment: getJSON does the conversion.... makes no sense to have to parse it when it would be JSON.

Answer (score 0):

```
cubes = [];
$.getJSON('urlaub.json', function(data) {
    var obj = data;
    for (elem in obj) {
        debugger
       cubes.push(obj[elem]);
        console.log(obj[elem]);
    };
    console.log(cubes);
});
```

i tried the above code it worked!!

Comment: set the debug at outsite the function. its empty

Answer (score 0):

[Docs for $.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/#jQuery-getJSON-url-data-success):

```
var cubes = null;
$.getJSON('urlaub.json', function(data) {
    cubes = data;
    console.log(cubes);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry @ll.
All your solutions works, my one too.
i was programming on an other working station. 
so i always saved the wrong files o O.

Please, im sorry. but much thanks for your help.

Thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

thanks,

```
var arr = [];     
var obj = data;     
$.each(obj,function(key,value){      
    arr.push("< LI>" + value + "< /LI>");      
});     
var val=arr.join('');      
console.log(val);
```

try it.

replace `LI` with `li`

Comment: var cubes = [];
$.getJSON('urlaub.json', function(data) {
 
 var obj = data;     
 $.each(obj,function(key,value){      
  cubes.push(value);      
 });     
 var val=cubes.join('');      
 console.log(val);
 
});


console.log(cubes); cubes is empty

Comment: same like you, but outside json function is cubes empty

Comment: u can try '<ul><li>'+ key +'</li>','<li>'+ value +'</li></ul>' in place of value